# React Native archive error: Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native" module is installed in your project dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcodebuild, xcode10

I'm trying to archive my (otherwise perfectly building, running on simulator/device for debug) iOS app built with React Native.

When I try to archive in Xcode, it compiles and links correctly but while trying to generate assets the following command is invoked:

`node '/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/React Native/REDACTED/node_modules/react-native/cli.js' bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/Can/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-eebdhuhscigvmvduljehleepetoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/REDACTED/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/REDACTED.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/Can/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-eebdhuhscigvmvduljehleepetoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/REDACTED/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/REDACTED.app`

It fails with error:

`error Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native" module is installed in your project dependencies.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

(Before you ask, **yes**, `react-native` is installed in my project dependencies, obviously)

When I invoke that exact node command manually, it generates assets perfectly fine:

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/Can/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-eebdhuhscigvmvduljehleepetoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/REDACTED/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/REDACTED.app/main.jsbundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 30 asset files
info Done copying assets
```

I am unable to archive my app because of this. It suggests me to run CLI with `--verbose` flag but I have no idea where to add the flag as the command itself is invoked from an autogenerated/complicated script.

What am I doing wrong? I am on Xcode 10.2 and React Native 0.59.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating some issues such as https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22354 I've found the problem after several hours:

I had a space in my project path. I've moved my project to a path without space and it started to archive perfectly. Apparently, it really was a bug with React Native.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error **Make sure "react-native" module is installed** you are not on the project root path. So delete the derived data and OPen Terminal & set Project Path

```
cd ../projectpath_foldername
```

run the command

```
npm start
```

after that

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Now run

```
react-native run-ios
```

once its build and run open the xcode and archive your app.

Comment: Actually I was running the code from React Native project root path, but I will try the other parts of your suggestion and update you.

Comment: Tried it. Everything built until the same point. Got the exact same error again.

Comment: you have run npm start

Comment: Stopped the Metro Bundler (using Ctrl+Z) and quite terminal

Comment: reopen and run react-native start

Comment: if still not work than quite metor and run  ```npm install -g react-native-cli --verbose```  in terminal after setting Root path of project and than run ```npm start
```
@CanPoyrazoğlu

Comment: I've found the problem. see my answer.